# as.Date dosen't work with %d-%b-%y (R)

Tags: r, date, as.date

I'm trying to convert dates in R from "1-Apr-02" to "2002-04-01", but `as.Date` does not recognise the format:

```
> as.Date("1-Apr-02", format="%d-%b-%y")
[1] NA
```

Even if I put a `"01"` instead of `"1"`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` and then try your code again.

Comment: Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C") fixes!! Thx

Comment: @DavidArenburg - would you like to explain why that works a bit more? Or how you figured that out, because it is a mystery to me.

Comment: @thelatemail I don't want to be rude or anything, but RTFM man :). `?as.Date` it all there...